# How to sum up the sums of grouped results with SQL by NOT altering the structure?

Tags: sql, data-structures, sql-server-2012, sum

I've got a column of names [name]), a column of integer values that I wanna sum up ([Values]) and another column of integer values ([Day]). I want to sum up the values grouped by name for each day. So for example if there is a name "Chris" with value 4 on day 1 and there is another entry "Chris" with value 2 on day 3, I want to show the sum of chris on day 1 (4) and on day 2 (4+2=6).

As in the example above ("chris") I wanna sum them up, showing the sum for each name on each day (the sum from day 1 until day x):

```
select name, day,
sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) total
from tablename
```

This works BUT: 
I actually need to keep the structure of the table since there is actually a further column with names (name2) I need to follow the original sequence of the data because each name is uniquely assigned to another name in another column of the same row. Then, In every row the names both are assigned to a specific value of this row. Later, I want to calculate with each pair of names respectively their values (sum of values) further results. 
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

[image: Table]

Sorry but I was not able to insert a table properly so here is an image showing that I want to create the red marked values based on my values in the 5 columns on the left.

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: I have added an image (see above)

Comment: As to the image: Just copy and paste the table as text into your request and then format it with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sum()` window function and `CTE`s:

```
with 
  ctable as (
    select t.*, row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
    from tablename t
  ),
  cte as (  
    select c.name, c.day, c.value, c.name2, c.value2,
    sum(c.value) over(order by rn) SumValue,
    sum(c.value2) over(order by rn) SumValue2
    from ctable c
  )
select c.*, SumValue + SumValue2 Result
from cte c
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=de01bf0c902d4d165b5faa3d9c11a40c).
Results:

```
> name  | day | value | name2 | value2 | SumValue | SumValue2 | Result
> :---- | --: | ----: | :---- | -----: | -------: | --------: | -----:
> Chris |   1 |     2 | Paul  |      5 |        2 |         5 |      7
> Alice |   1 |     5 | Ken   |      4 |        7 |         9 |     16
> Paul  |   2 |     8 | Alice |      1 |       15 |        10 |     25
> Ken   |   2 |    11 | Chris |      2 |       26 |        12 |     38
> Alice |   3 |    14 | Ken   |      3 |       40 |        15 |     55
> Chris |   3 |    17 | Paul  |      0 |       57 |        15 |     72
```

I used `SumValue + SumValue2` to calculate the result because in the question you say: *"sum of values"*. But in the expected results you use the multiplication symbol `*`. If you don't want the sum but the product then change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you but this code does not respect that the sum should be created for each name at each day. Your example sums up every value no matter which name it is. To follow your example: I would like to have in SumValue for Chris 2 and the second entry at the bottom of the table should have SumValue= 5. For Alice the first entry should be 5, the second entry (second last line) should have SumValue = 4...I need to create the values for each name. Thank you your support is amazing

Comment: The results in my code are the same as the expected results you posted in your question. What you mention in your comment has nothing to do with these expected results.

Comment: Sorry I've just realized you are right. The table I've posted does not represent what I have asked for in the text. Since this is not an elementary difference are you still able to help me or should I post a new question?

Comment: It is the 2nd question that you post on this subject. In both cases you posted new requirements after you got answers. This is not how it works here in SO. Read this:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 So if an answer solves the problem **as you posted it** then you accept that answer by checking the checkmark at the left. If not then mention it in a comment. But don't change the requirement because then you invalidate all the answers. If the requirement is different than the one you posted then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you just want to add `name2` to the `partition by` clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(value) over (partition by name, name2 order by day) as total
from tablename  t;
```

Comment: Thank you this seemed to be promising but I only get the sum for each day and name separately. My goal is to add always the latest value to the sum of all previous days. So for Name Z on Day X i want to show the sum of all values from day Day 1 until Day X.

Comment: @blowbuh . . . This does a cumulative sum.  That is how `over` with `order by` works.

Answer (score 0):

From the image you linked to from your request it seems you want running totals on `order by day, value`:

```
select 
  t.*
  sum(value) over (order by day, value) as sumvalue,
  sum(value2) over (order by day, value) as sumvalue2,
  sum(value) over (order by day, value) * sum(value2) over (order by day, value) as result
from tablename t
order by day, value;
```